# Regex to Not Match Certain Digits at Specific Positions

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I am trying to write a RegEx that will match a 6-digit number if the middle two digits are not on an exclusion list.

For example if the exclusion list is (02, 05) I want to match only the first of these numbers

```
880199
880299
880599
```

The closest I have come is the exact opposite of what I intend with the RegEx

```
\b[0-9]{2}(02|05)\w+
```

I read the linked information "A regex question?" and in particular the section "Negation is tricky."

I can't figure out how to negate the match.

The solution must be a RegEx because it is being used in an extension point of an online platform that only offers RegEx as an option. It needs to be as language agnostic as possible because it must run on that platform (which I believe is written in PHP) as well as under .NET.

My current attempt (which matches the inverse of what is desired) is at http://regexr.com/3da5n

Comment: Always the 3rd and 4th digits? [`\b[0-9]{2}(?!02|05)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/kD7rZ9/1). Is the exclusion list dynamic?

Comment: [`\b[0-9]{2}(?!0[25])[0-9]*`](https://regex101.com/r/kD2sC8/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes always those digits. The list is not dynamic per se, but variants of it will be applied in many places. It's not always 02 and 05.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you need to use a negative lookahead to restrict the matches. The lookahead should check the middle 2 digits, so it should be placed right after the first two:

```
\b\d{2}(?!02|05)\d+\b
       ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kD7rZ9/2)

If the list is not dynamic, you can further enhance the alternations as `\b\d{2}(?!0[25])\d+\b`.

The pattern matches:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?!02|05)` - check if the next 2 digits are `02` or `05` and if yes, fail the match
- `\d+` - 1+ digits (if there should only be six digits in a word, use `\d{4}`)
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

Comment: I have updated the comment *if there should only be six digits in a word, use `\d{4}`* instead of `\d+`. Glad to help.